# Combine two if statements for different variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two variables for two different purposes to produce some information, but I wanted to see if there was a more convenient way for me to write this out:

```
var One = 0;
var Team = 0;

if(items[i].NumberOfAttendees == '1' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'One')
{
    One += 1;
}
else if(items[i].NumberOfAttendees == '1' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'Team') 
{
    Team += 1;
}
else if(items[i].NumberOfAttendees == '2' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'One') 
{
    One += 2;
}
else if(items[i].NumberOfAttendees == '2' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'Team') 
{
    Team += 2;
}

etc...
```

Is there a more convenient way to call this but to also keep the `One` and `Team` count separated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume **items** is an array of objects.

You can simply loop over this array using a for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
}
```

Inside this loop get the value of **ApplicationType** and using a switch-block decide what to do if it's either **Team** or **One**. Once that's decided check the value of **NumberOfAttendees** and if it's greater than 0 add it's value to either the Team or One variable.

```
var attendees;
var One = 0;
var Team = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  switch (items[i].ApplicationType) {
    case "Team":
      attendees = parseInt(items[i].NumberOfAttendees);
      if (attendees > 0) {
        Team += attendees;
      }
      break;

    case "One":
      attendees = parseInt(items[i].NumberOfAttendees);
      if (attendees > 0) {
        One += attendees;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @obscure, this worked like a charm!

How would I apply the same logic to this:             `if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Windows' && items[i].RequestType == 'Single User' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'OneDrive')
            {
                ODwindows += 1;
            }
            if(items[i].ComputerType == 'Windows' && items[i].RequestType == 'Single User' && items[i].ApplicationType == 'OneDrive')
            {
                Tmac += 1;
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(items[i].ApplicationType == 'One') One+= +items[i].NumberOfAttendees;
if(items[i].ApplicationType == 'Team') Team+= +items[i].NumberOfAttendees;
```

```js
var One = 0;
var Team = 0;

var items=[
  {ApplicationType:'One', NumberOfAttendees:'1'},
  {ApplicationType:'One', NumberOfAttendees:'1'},
  {ApplicationType:'One', NumberOfAttendees:'2'},
  {ApplicationType:'Team', NumberOfAttendees:'1'},
  {ApplicationType:'Team', NumberOfAttendees:'2'},
];

for(let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
  if(items[i].ApplicationType == 'One') One+= +items[i].NumberOfAttendees;
  if(items[i].ApplicationType == 'Team') Team+= +items[i].NumberOfAttendees;
}

console.log({One, Team});
```